# Making quantum gates bigger in size using Qucircuit

Tags: size, qcircuit

I am drawing some quantum circuits by using `Qcircuit` latex package, and the size of the gates is small for the document as my purpose right now is just to show the Pauli gates in a figure.

I would like to know if there is a way to make this gates bigger in size in order to have a better visualization of them in the document.

The code I am using is

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\leavevmode
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
& \gate{X}  & \qw &  &\gate{Y} & \qw  &  & \gate{Z} & \qw
}
\caption{Schematic representation of Pauli gates for quantum circuits.}
\label{fig:pauligates}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the font size with `\Huge`/`\LARGE`/`\Large`/`\large`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qcircuit}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\leavevmode
\Huge % or \LARGE or \Large or \large
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
& \gate{X}  & \qw &  &\gate{Y} & \qw  &  & \gate{Z} & \qw
}
\caption{Schematic representation of Pauli gates for quantum circuits.}
\label{fig:pauligates}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```